# Load an HTML partial into a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, partials

Help!

I have a main page (index.html), and a few partial pages (just HTML files). I'm trying to load one of those partials into a div on my index.html page when clicking a link in the nav bar. I thought JQuery would be best for this, but the partial never loads and I get this error message "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." I'm not sure what's causing this-- it seems like pretty straightforward code. Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 

       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>




</head>

 <body>

 <div id="nav">


    <ul>
    <li><a href="partials/art.html">art</a></li>

            <li><a href="partials/design.html">   design</a></li>

            <li><a href="#" id="load_illustration">   illustration</a></li>

            <li><img src="images/LOGO.png" height="150" width="160"    alt="logo"></li>

         <li><a href="partials/about.html">   about</a></li>

         <li><a href="">   cv</a></li>

         <li><a href="partials/contact.html">   contact</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>

     <div id="include">

      </div>

   <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#load_illustration").on("click", function(){
    $("#include").load("partials/illustration.html");
    });
   });


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you run your code from the file system (file:///).

Error message you got, says: "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http ...".

This means, you should run your code using local web server, for example, apache.